# Webform depending on Select List - Number of delegates

Tags: webforms

Webform 4.x

On a Webform booking form how would one add the functionality where from a dropdown list of number of delegates (1,2,3...) would then add the necessary number fields on the form. So if 1 was selected from a list then only 1 set of fields is presented, but if 2 is selected from the list then 2 set of fields is presented.

For example:

Booking Contact Name:
 Booking Email address:
 Number of Delegates:(Select options: 1,2,3,4,5...) Number 2 Selected!

Delegate Name:
 Delegate Date of Birth:

Delegate Name:
 Delegate Date of Birth:

Comment: Try Webform conditionals module (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional)

Answer (score 0):

I would create conditionals. E.g. if Number of Delegates is 2, then show the second pair of fields. If it is 3, show the third...

You can consider this solution if the number of delegates is limited.